# Change storage Disk for Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bash, storage, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had recently installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux in my Notebook, where I have two disk for storage:
 - C:/ an SSD of 128GB
 - D:/ an HDD of 1TB
By default the Windows Subsystem for Linux its installed on my C disk, but that's got me without space. Does it exist any way to change the Subsystem Installation to the other disk (D)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Relevant: [Can I move the linux subsystem to a different drive?](//superuser.com/q/1113906)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779801/move-wsl-bash-on-windows-root-filesystem-to-another-hard-drive/